# how to add clipper to navigation drawer in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created a navigation drawer.But I don't know how to add clipper using custom_clippers package

I want to add clipper image in the header section of my drawer.

here is the code

```
Widget _createHeader() {
    return DrawerHeader(
//        margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
//        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,

        child:ClipPath(
          clipper: SideCutClipper(),
          child: Container(
            height: 600,
            width: 500  ,
            color: Colors.pink))
               ,


//        decoration: BoxDecoration(
//            image: DecorationImage(
//                fit: BoxFit.fill,
//                image:  AssetImage('path/to/header_background.png'))),
        child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
          Positioned(
              bottom: 12.0,
              left: 16.0,
              child: Text("Flutter Step-by-Step",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500))),
        ]));
  }
```

Comment: Can you explain more please? You code runs fine and it clips the widget. What exactly you want to achieve? Adding a sample image would help a lot.

Comment: two childs inside a widget ..it is unusual...this code is not working because I have used two childs

Comment: With a few edits that will be fixed, did you fix the problem?

Comment: I DID THIS:-return DrawerHeader(
        margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
       padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
       child: Center(
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(16),
          child: ClipPath(
              clipper: SideCutClipper(),
              child: Image.network('https://images.pexels.com/photos/414171/pexels-photo-414171.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500')
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

Comment: @Arash Mohammadi please answer this question in real box.. It will be helpful for other beginners

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Few Edits to brackets and parentheses:

```
Widget _createHeader() {
return DrawerHeader(
  child: ClipPath(
    clipper: SideCutClipper(),
    child: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
       image: DecorationImage(
           fit: BoxFit.fill,
           image:  AssetImage('images/Rectangle-image.png'))),
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Positioned(
            bottom: 12.0,
            left: 16.0,
            child: Text(
              "Flutter Step-by-Step",
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

**Tip**

Use , (comma) after parentheses and brackets and reformat your code (Alt + Shift + F in VSCode). This will make debugging  a lot easier, helps with documentation, makes code pretty and ... .